# Getting users information from the website booking.com

Tags: javascript, android, ios, rest

I need to know whether [booking.com](http://www.booking.com/index.it.html?sid=32374f9c0878f11513f29fd721ac42de;dcid=4) exposes any API for developers like facebook or twitter does.

I Cannot find anything on its website. Shall I contact directly the website in order to know this.

If not, Is there any way to get, for instance, all the comments from a specific user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booking.com exposes and API for its affiliate partners. You therefore need to become an affiliate partner to use their API.

On [their site](http://www.booking.com/content/affiliate-help.html) they state who can become one and how

> We welcome anyone who's interested in offering the best choice of accommodations! For example, you might be a website owner with qualified content and dedicated traffic, a (travel) app developer, or an online/offline travel agent. Certain rules and guidelines do apply, which you can read under the "Sign Up" link on the left menu

[This blog post](http://www.innoraft.com/blog/importing-hotels-bookingcom-nodes-using-its-api) offers an overview of said API.

Comment: are they free of charge?

Comment: I don´t know, that was not part of your question. I would suggest just trying to become a partner. If they dont ask for credit cards, it probably is free ;)

Comment: I correct myself: `Signing up is totally free.`!